# Getting ahold of the Application to call its method

Tags: apache-flex, interface, flex4, flex4.5

In my Flex 4.5 application I have a TitleWindow **Settings.mxml**, which is popped up by the PopUpManager.

Once the user has changed some settings, I not only need to save them to a SharedObject, but also to apply them to the main Application itself - so that the changes are visible to the user immediately.

For example I need to call its method **hideApp(somevalue);**

The [spark.components.Application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html) does not seem to have any static/singleton methods to get ahold of it.

So how do you do it?

And I also wonder how to declare, that an MXML file implements one or several interfaces?

```
package {
  public interface Hiddable {
    function hideApp(value:Number):void;
  }
}
```

I'm asking this, because besides the main Application I have a **SettingsTest.mxml** Application in my project for "unit testing" that particular functionality.

Thank you! Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About implementing of interfaces in MXML components see [the following documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf688f1-7ff1.html).

What about passing changed data back from your pop up window to the application I recommend you to use [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#ActionScript) with Flash event model something like the following:

```
var myWindow:MyWindow = MyWindow(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, MyWindow));
myWindow.addEventListener(MyWindowEvent.SUBMIT, myWindowSubmit);

private function myWindow(event:MyWindowEvent):void
{
    // Unsubscribing from events
    var myWindow:MyWindow = MyWindow(event.currentTarget);
    myWindow.removeEventListener(MyWindowEvent.SUBMIT, myWindowSubmit);
    // Changed data is passing with custom event object
    someData = event.someData;
}
```

And you should implement your custom event for that (`MyWindowEvent` in my pseudo code) and fire it from your `TitleWindow` component. You can read more about implementing custom event [in documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a22.html).

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication
```

though I would recommend you use events to avoid tight coupling.

As for the question about interfaces: use the attribute `implements`

```
<s:Component ... implements="IClassA,IClassB" ... />
```